# Organized Combined Array From Parse By Date

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I combined PFObject arrays together that I got from Parse...

```
array.appendContentsOf(otherArray)
```

How would I take this one big array and organize it by when they were created?

Here is basically what my query is, I took out most stuff and changed some stuff around so it would make sense if you didn't see my entire class...

```
func loadStuff() {

    let postQuery = PFQuery(className: "Post")

    postQuery.orderByDescending("createdAt")

    postQuery.whereKey("type", equalTo: "world")

    postQuery.whereKey("distance", equalTo: distanceType)

    postQuery.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: PFGeoPoint(location: currentLocation), withinMiles: miles)

    postQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
        if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {

          // Remove content from arrays if it's the first query

            if error == nil {
                if arrayOfPosts.isEmpty == false {
                    for post in arrayOfPosts {

                     // Append stuff

                        if queryIsComplete == true {

                            if query == 0 {
                                self.loadStuff()

                            } else if query == 1 {

                                self.loadStuff()

                            } else {

                                self.arrays.appendContentsOf(self.arrayFromQuery1)
                                self.arrays.appendContentsOf(self.arrayFromQuery2)
                                self.arrays.appendContentsOf(self.arrayFromQuery3)

                                self.arrays.sortInPlace({ $0.createdAt!.compare($1.createdAt!) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending })

                                self.table.reloadData()

                            }


                        }


                    }

                }

            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: The answer by @DavidWong looks right to me.  Be sure to apply the sort to the *combined* results of the queries.  (And be sure to understand that the queries are probably asynchronous, the complete result won't be sort-able until *all* of the queries are complete).  You should probably post a minimal version of your query code (and show where you are applying David Wong's advice).

Comment: @danh Ok I'm going to try a few things. And if none work I'll post some of my query.

Comment: @danh I added the query.

Comment: In trying to simplify (which is appreciated!!) you might have edited out something essential.  There need to be three queries and they need to *all* be finished before you can combine the results.  Three can be done with Parse.Query.or() or by nesting a query in another's completion block, or by performing them in cloud code on a promise chain.  One way or another, you should first establish the origin of (and validity of) arrayFromQuery1, arrayFromQuery2, and arrayFromQuery3 before even attempting the more trivial matter of sorting the combined results.

Comment: @danh How would I check if a query is complete?

Comment: It will be complete within its completion block.  Please reread my previous comment for ways to combine (and establish completeness for) more than one query.

Comment: @danh I did. And above in my query I check if it's complete with error == nil. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You've posted only one query.  Its completion block contains three undefined  (as far as I can tell)  arrays named arrayFromQuery1,2,3

Comment: @danh Yeah I'm sorry about that. Basically each array comes from each query. I do 3 queries. I do it first in the view did load. Then in my completion block I do it once again by calling the method. Then I do it one last time. Then finally when that third query is finished, I append all the arrays I got from each query into one big array.

Comment: You should be wrapping up your queries in NSOperations (however a topic way too big for this.) I suggest you look at Apple's Advanced Operation https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-226/ With this you can add dependencies on the three queries operations and in the finishing code do the sorting. Also, it keeps your logic in neat reusable objects.

Comment: @DavidWong the OP can but doesn't have to wrap the queries in NSOperation to have them perform asynch nor to have them chained.  The SDK has them run on a background thread and invoke a block on the main when they are done.  I've outlined a couple common and good approaches in comment above.  The OP *may* be doing this by nesting calls in the completion blocks, but it is unclear from what's been posted so far.  I think I'll be able to help when I see all three queries.

Comment: @danh I did some tests. I put a button above the table and when pressed it sorts the array and reloads the table. It still doesn't sort it correctly. I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Lets try this: make a brand new method that does all three queries, nesting each within the completion block of the previous one.  In the innermost completion block, sort the objects as @DavidWong suggests.  Log the createdAt dates before and after the sort.  Please post that code and the log output here.  It will either work or we'll have a path to find whats wrong.

Comment: @danh Oh wait! I got it. I was doing it to the wrong array! Can't believe I missed this. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're fetching a whole lot of records asynchronously so:

```
array.sortInPlace { $0.createdAt.compare($1.createdAt) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending }
```

Comment: For some reason this didn't worked. Is it because I combined three arrays?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to know when each object was created inside of your array,you will put a condition before you start the query from parse  using the timestamp `createAt` or `updateAt`

```
 var timeStamp = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: -1200)
 query.whereKey("createdAt", greaterThanOrEqualTo: timeStamp)
```

Then you could order your list just like the following

```
   query.orderByDescending("createdAt")   //either Ascending or Descending
```

So now you will do what my friend @DavidWong propose into the top post :)

Comment: Yeah I did the second one, which works. But I do 3 querys with 3 separate arrays. Which I combine together. So it gets thrown out of order.